# How to Access Vue.js (or Express) env variables in an API endpoint

Tags: node.js, api, express, vue.js, environment-variables

I have a folder called `/api` in the root of the application where I access an endpoint from the Frontend `/src` to send an email. I'd like to call an environment variable here but it is not working with `process.env.VUE_APP_APIKEY`. What is the right way to do this?

This is the endpoint I am calling the env variable from. This is using express:

```
let endpoint = function(app) {
  app.post('/send-mail', function(req, res) {
    sgMail.setApiKey(process.env.VUE_APP_APIKEY);
    sgMail
      .send(req.body)
      .then(() => {
        // do something
      })
      .catch(error => {
        // do something
      });

    return res.send(req.body);
  });
};
```

That `sgMail` is sendgrid, hence the API key I'm calling is for that service.

Comment: Are you getting any errors? Is `VUE_APP_APIKEY` defined as an environment variable?

Comment: No, the env variable works in the frontend correctly, but since /api is not inside /src then I think Vue env variables aren't available.

Comment: Yes that is correct. Your Vue app is running on an entirely different process than your Express application. So you need to define them in both places.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to define your env vars somewhere. `process.env` returns an object containing all the user environment.

You can define your env vars when you run `node`, by doing something like this:

```
MY_VAR=my_value node server.js
```

An easy way to manage your environment variables with Node.js is to use [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv).

Create a `.env` file at the root of your repo or anywhere (depending on your needs) and add your env vars like this:

```
VUE_APP_APIKEY=[API KEY VALUE]
```

Then add the following line of code into your `server.js` or `index.js` (where your Express is instantiated):

```
require('dotenv').config()
```

Hence you should be able to use your env vars by using your existing code: `process.env.VUE_APP_APIKEY`.

Comment: Thanks, do you know of anyway to do this natively with Vue?

Comment: Based on the name of your env var, you're using Vue CLI, right? In that case, you can add your env vars within a `.env` file (without using dotenv) and prefix all of them by `VUE_APP_`.

Comment: Thanks but doesn't work, I think it needs to be inside /src folder for it to work.

Comment: Thanks, fyi just had to use env package and created a file and it's being read globaly. So I guess I'm stuck with Vue env variables for front end stuff, and a regular .env file for API stuff.

Comment: Yes, your `.env` file must be into the root folder of your frontend code, `/src` in your case. Cool if everything works ;-)